# How to get spotipy playlist results in list format

Tags: python, spotipy

I'm using spotipy to get a list of my playlists. I use

```
if token:
sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth=token)
playlists = sp.user_playlists(username)
for item in playlists['items']:
    id= item['uri']
    print id
```

This returns a list of playlist uri's that looks like

> spotify:user:ultramusicofficial:playlist:0gvQoG7iMMz8L5Ltsa4lkT
>   spotify:user:spotify:playlist:4Ha7Qja6HY3AgvNBgWz87p
>   spotify:user:ministryofsounduk:playlist:7grWVkJDQpcBie8oqKP6hv

But there is something weird about the way it returns them. It's not a normal list and I can't seem to make it into one. If I use

```
print id[1]
```

It would return something like

```
p

p

p
```

I want to be able to do something like

```
print id[1]
```

and have it return

> spotify:user:spotify:playlist:4Ha7Qja6HY3AgvNBgWz87p

I've tried joining it and splicing it in different ways, I've tried using it as a tuple, converting it to a string. Nothing works I'm clearly very unsure what to do. I feel like it's probably a simple and I'm just missing it. Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just printing the id, not gathering them into a list, so your id is the last item from the loop which is a single `uri` (a string). You can use a list comprehension to make a list out of the for loop:

```
id = [item['uri'] for item in playlists['items']]
```

---

Or start with an empty list and append the result to it:

```
id = []
for item in playlists['items']:
    id.append(item['uri'])
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It was a simple answer I think I over complicated it with other methods I tried earlier and just couldn't get it. When I tried a comprehension I messed that up and did it the same as the one in my code. I'm so happy to finally have this working thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In your example `id` is a string.  So id[1] is the second character, which is `p`